# How to refresh my dynamic IP address on my router using dhcp client

Tags: router

I would like to change my dynamic IP on my ISP's router without restarting the router. I can already telnet to a busy box shell and can issue the following commands

```
zebra        swapdev      printserver  ln           ebtables     cat
wpsd         startbsp     pppc         klog         dns          busybox
wlancmd      sntp         ping         kill         dms          brctl
web          smbpasswd    ntfs-3g      iwpriv       dhcps        atserver
usbserver    smbd         nmbd         iwconfig     dhcpc        atmcmd
usbmount     sleep        netstat      iptables     ddnsc        atcmd
upnp         siproxd      mount        ipp          date         at
upg          sh           mldproxy     ipcheck      cwmp         ash
umount       scanner      mknod        ip           cp           adslcmd
tr111        rm           mkdir        igmpproxy    console      acl
tr064        ripd         mii_mgr      hw_nat       cms          ac
telnetd      reg          mic          ethcmd       cli
tc           radvdump     ls           equipcmd     chown
switch       ps           log          echo         chmod
#
```

Here is the output of #top to which processes are already running on router

```
PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %MEM %CPU COMMAND
  857   856 0        R     1808   3%   0% top
  281     1 0        S     4316   7%   0% cms
  275   110 0        S     3268   5%   0% mic
  279     1 0        S     2916   5%   0% log
  854   853 0        S     2908   5%   0% telnet_cli -l 1
  541     1 0        S     2512   4%   0% dhcps
  565     1 0        S     2260   4%   0% pppc -I ppp257
  717     1 0        S     2200   4%   0% dhcpc -i nas0 -I nas0 -a -v HG533FTTx
  856   854 0        S     1812   3%   0% sh -si
    1     0 0        S     1808   3%   0% init
  110     1 0        S     1808   3%   0% -/bin/sh
  254     1 0        S     1768   3%   0% atserver
  742     1 0        S     1416   2%   0% usbmount
  551     1 0        S     1408   2%   0% dns
  277     1 0        S     1360   2%   0% klog
  539     1 0        S     1104   2%   0% ipcheck
  853   275 0        S     1048   2%   0% /bin/telnetd -s 14 -t 0
  415     1 0        S     1040   2%   0% wpsd
   88     1 0        SW       0   0%   0% [mtdblockd]
    4     1 0        SW<      0   0%   0% [khelper]
```

The router is a HG533 Huawei

I need to restart the dhclient to get a new ip address without a reboot of the router. I am not sure what dhclient is used my guess is it is udhcp.

These two commands are in the Process List provided by #ps

```
565 0           576 S   pppc -I ppp257
717 0           332 S   dhcpc -i nas0 -I nas0 -a -v HG533FTTx<v1.14t>
```

Thanks

Comment: Some router assigns DHCP IP address according to the MAC address of the client. So do not be surprised if you get the same IP address after a new request.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the `dhcpc` command to release and renew the DHCP lease, which --may-- give you a new IP address, but despite the confusing 'dynamic' term, DHCP servers tend to give the same host the same IP address for the duration of the configured DHCP lease time, if the DHCP pool is large enough to address all unique clients making requests.  At 1/2 the lease time, a client with a valid lease will renew its lease on the same IP, to facilitate persistence in IP parameters.  If the DHCP server had been reset since the original lease was given out, the renewal request will more than likely be honoured, as the lease can't be successfully re-leased to another client while the first lessee is still occupying that address.  While it's been many years since I've worked on ISP DHCP configurations, there had not been an eviction or abandon function available to either server or client.

This is to prevent poorly connected clients from hopping from IP address to IP address in a short timespan, or having very long sessions fail when the client is forced to change IP addresses after its lease expires.

Comment: Yet when I reboot the router I get a new lease. And my IP changes.

Answer (score 0):

"killall pppc" command drops ppp connection and renews wan ip.
in my HG658c works like a charm. hope works on your router.